# Distributed nodes to sync data without a single point of failure

Tags: real-time, distributed-system

Recently I've been reading about methods to horizontally scale a server.

The majority of methods, if not all, require a central server to sync the data (Redis is widely used here). That means that multiple nodes rely on one central server, one point of failure, to have data synced between them.

I know that I can have multiple instances of Redis and those nodes can connect to the backup Redis servers and keep syncing the data just in case the main Redis server fails, but I dont like the idea to have "2 layers" (Server layer and Redis layer) to achieve this. Is there any piece of software, or method, to have multiple nodes be synced between them only being connected between them?

I mean, like having the 3 Redis servers installed in the same 3 Server machines. If one servers goes down, it goes down along with the Redis server, so the other 2 Server machines connect to the fallback Redis server installed on their own machines, but instead of this hackish thingy, have a piece of software that simply connect between the nodes, sync the data and such.

I've been thinking on a system, but one problem arises. A problem that can be extended to the "having multiple Redis instances" thing.

Imagine that I have a system with X Redis servers in different datacenters, and also have X servers in different datacenters too. I don't want them in the same datacenter to avoid single point of failures. Now, let's say that half of the servers lose the connection to the other half, not because of machines going down, but because of connection failures (ISP problem and such). The slaves are going to think that the master Redis server is dead because the connection dropped and they cannot reconnect, and the same with part of the servers that also lost the connection, that are going to think that the master Redis is dead, and connect and sync data using the slaves.

Now we have an scenario of one master Redis server with X servers syncing data between them and some slave Redis servers with other X servers syncing data between them.

With this, all the distributed system to not have a single point of failure is a failure by itself, because still has a single point of failure that, instead of make people lose data, will make the system have unsynced garbage data.

And as it will be realtime data, having a "save timestamps a resync data when connection recovers in a few minutes" is not a solution.

What do you think? Any solution?

Comment: Read:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science), as well as look up "raft algorithm"

Comment: @Amit Those are great readings. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm glad it's helpful, but it's not an answer... Links only answers are not allowed...

Comment: @Amit Oh, what a pity...